# airbrake config for heroku+rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, airbrake

I'm trying to configure airbrake, but can't figure it out. What I wanna achieve is  not getting errors from `development` and `test` envs only from production.

With the following setup though, I'm getting all the 3 types of error messages as they were occurred in production. So production error sends production error notification but development/test error also sends production error notification.

How can I configure it properly?

```
# Configures the environment the application is running in. Helps the Airbrake
# dashboard to distinguish between exceptions occurring in different
# environments. By default, it's not set.
# NOTE: This option must be set in order to make the 'ignore_environments'
# option work.
# https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake-ruby#environment
c.environment = :production 

# Setting this option allows Airbrake to filter exceptions occurring in
# unwanted environments such as :test. By default, it is equal to an empty
# Array, which means Airbrake Ruby sends exceptions occurring in all
# environments.
# NOTE: This option *does not* work if you don't set the 'environment' option.
# https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake-ruby#ignore_environments
c.ignore_environments = %w(test, development)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You configure your ignored environments like this:

```
c.ignore_environments = %w(test, development)
# Which is equivalent to:
c.ignore_environments = ['test,', 'development']
```

The correct way to configure this option is this:

```
c.ignore_environments = %w(test development)
# Which is equivalent to:
c.ignore_environments = ['test', 'development']
```

If you use Ruby's `%w` syntax for arrays, you don't want to use commas.

Another potential issue is that you specify:

```
c.environment = :production
```

It will be more robust to use a String (instead of a Symbol) or `Rails.env` here.

```
c.environment = Rails.env
```

Comment: kyrylo, hahaha. I put it even `irb` just to make sure it sends back the array properly. Somehow I missed it :). The `c.environment = :production` is from the official docs. I'm confused when it comes to `Rails.env`. The docs say `By default, it's not set`, but the default value was `Rails.env`, which seems to be contradiction to me.

Comment: By default, airbrake-ruby as a library doesn't set it. But the airbrake gem has a Rails initialiser, which knows that a Rails app most likely will use `Rails.env`, so it conveniently configures this for you. As for the docs, they also use symbols for `ignore_environments`, so this behaviour is consistent there. Happy Airbraking!